# Sort data in VBA doesn't execute

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I tried to copy the worksheet RLDSht in the first workbook in to my 2nd workbook. Then it's called USSht worksheet.
I want to sort data in this USSht but it doesn't execute even when I Activate the worksheet. Here is the code:

```
Public WorkbookName As String
Public WorkbookVV As Workbook
Public RLDSht As Worksheet
Public USSub As Worksheet
Public NoGrey As Worksheet
Public ws As Worksheet

Sub SelectWorkbook()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

WorkbookName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xlsm), *xlsm", 1, "Select your workbook", , False)
If WorkbookName <> "False" Then
    Set WorkbookVV = Workbooks.Open(WorkbookName)
    
    For Each ws In WorkbookVV.Sheets
        If Not ws.Cells.Find("Data type") Is Nothing Then
            RLDShtExist = True
            Set RLDSht = ws
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    
    If RLDShtExist = False Then
        MsgBox "Erreur: Le workbook sélectionné ne contient pas d'onglet Regulatory Line Data"
        WorkbookName = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

If RLDSht.FilterMode Then RLDSht.ShowAllData

RLDSht.Copy after:=Workbooks("US Submission table.xlsm").Worksheets("US Submission Table")
Set Ussht = ActiveSheet

With Ussht
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    lR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'last column
    lC = .Cells(lR, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'first row
    fR = .Cells(lR, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set cdt = Range(.Cells(fR, 1), .Cells(fR, lC)).Find("Data type")
    If Not cdt Is Nothing Then
        c = cdt.Column
    Else
        MsgBox "La colonne Data type n'est pas présenté dans ce tab RLD"
    End If
    


End With
Ussht.Activate
Ussht.Range(Cells(fR, 1), Cells(fR, lC)).Sort Key1:=Range("A12"), Order1:=xlDescending

End Sub
```

I also tried different range with reference cells, don't work either

```
Ussht.Range(Cells(fR, 1), Cells(fR, lC)).Sort Key1:=Range(Cells(fR, 1), Cells(fR, 1)), Order1:=xlDescending
```

I also try syntax Key/order instead of Key1/Order1.

It only work when I try something really precise like this:

```
Ussht.Range("A12:AB1740").Sort Key1:=Range("A12"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

what can be a problem with `Range(Cells(fR, 1), Cells(fR, lC))` please?

Comment: Yes I just fixed the formatting. Thank you

Comment: Hope this time is better

Comment: `Ussht.Range(Cells(fR, 1), Cells(fR, lC)).Sort` you have first row fR twice . 2nd one should be lR.

Answer (score 2):

### Import Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWorksheet()

    Dim sFilePath: sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        "Excel files (*.xlsm), *xlsm", , "Select your workbook")
    If VarType(sFilePath) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, shCell As Range
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
        Set shCell = sws.UsedRange.Find( _
            "Data Type", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
        If Not shCell Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next sws
    
    If sws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Erreur: Le workbook sélectionné ne contient " _
            & "pas d'onglet Regulatory Line Data", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If this is the workbook containing this code, use 'Set dwb = Thisworkbook'
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("US Submission table.xlsm")
    Dim aws As Worksheet: Set aws = dwb.Sheets("US Submission Table")
    
    sws.Copy After:=aws
    
    Dim hAddress As String: hAddress = shCell.Address
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = aws.Next
    
    Dim dhCell As Range: Set dhCell = dws.Range(hAddress) ' Data Type
    Dim dfRow As Long: dfRow = dhCell.Row
    
    Dim dfCol As Long, dlCol As Long, dlrow As Long
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        dfCol = .Column
        dlCol = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column
        dlrow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With
        
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dws.Range(dws.Cells(dfRow, dfCol), dws.Cells(dlrow, dlCol))

    drg.Sort drg.Columns(1), xlDescending, , , , , , xlYes

    ' Continue...

End Sub
```